# scrlttr2: change letter and phone symbol

Tags: symbols, koma-script, scrlttr2

I am writing a letter of motivation by using the document class `scrlttr2`. In my letter foot I want my address and phone number to appear. Is there a way I can change the predefined symbols?

My code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,backaddress=off,foldmarks=false,parskip=half,addrfield=false]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
\usepackage{marvosym} % Allows the use of symbol
\usepackage{csquotes}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}

\renewcommand{\normalsize}{\fontsize{12.5}{17}\selectfont}
\let\raggedsignature\raggedright

\makeatletter
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{\parskip}
\@setplength{refvpos}{\useplength{toaddrvpos}}
\makeatother

\setkomavar{fromname}{LM}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{abc}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{123}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{abc@posteo.net}
\setkomavar{place}{z}
\setkomavar{signature}{LM}

\setkomavar{firsthead} {
\centering
{\fontsize{18}{18}\selectfont Letter of Motivation}\\[1mm]
\fontsize{12}{12}\selectfont LM} 
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{
\centering

{
\renewcommand{\\}{\ {\textperiodcentered}\ }
\usekomavar{fromaddress}
}\\
{\Letter} \usekomavar{fromemail} \ {\Telefon} \usekomavar{fromphone}}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Company\\Address\\City}

\setkomavar{subject}{Position Title}
\opening{Dear Recruiter,}
Content goes here.

\closing{Sincerely yours,}

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What's your problem? If you want to replace the symbols at your own foot definition just use another symbol font and replace, e.g., `\Telefon` by the symbol of that font. You may also replace it by an `\includegraphics` command. If you want to replace the symbols at the predefined letter head (e.g., the sender block) you may have a look at option `symbolicnames`, which changes the defaults of the *description* of `phoneseparator` etc. You can change them to whatever you want using `\setkomavar*`.

Comment: Hi Laura. Was one of the answer below helpfull though? If yes, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 4):

**Enabling the display of your phone number**

To let your phone number be displayed, you need to add the option `fromphone` (idem for `frommail`, etc.) to the document class declaration:

```
\documentclass[fromphone]{scrlttr2}
```

Note that you can switch this option on later, using following command in your preamble:

```
\documentclass{scrlttr2}
\KOMAoptions{fromphone}
```

**Customizing the symbol preceding your phone number**

By default, the `scrlttr2` class uses `marvosym` symbols (see *§4.10. Note Paper* in the documentation -- more exactly on p. 178). If you want to change the symbol by the one of your choice, you should use the optional argument of the `\setkomavar{fromXXX}` command as following:

```
\setkomavar{fromphone}[<the symbol you want to use>]{01234567890}
```

---

**MWE**

(here, only the phone symbol was customized using a right-pointing hand instead)

[image]

```
\documentclass[fromemail]{scrlttr2}%<== the display of the email is enabled in the documentclass declaration
    \KOMAoptions{fromphone}%<== the display of the phone number is enabled later, in the preamble
    \usepackage{fontawesome}%<== package for using other symbols (check the The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List)
\begin{document}
    \setkomavar{fromname}{John Public}
    \setkomavar{fromaddress}{Valley 2\\
        54321 Public-Village}
    \setkomavar{fromphone}[\faHandORight~]{0\,12\,34~56\,78}%<== customize with your own logo
    \setkomavar{fromemail}{Peter@Public.invalid}%<== no optional argument: default symbol is used

    \begin{letter}{%
            Joana Public\\
            Hillside 1\\
            12345 Public-City%
        }
        \opening{Dear chairman,}

        the last general meeting was about one year ago.
        I want to remind you, that the constitution of our club advises you to make a general meeting every six month.
        Because of this I expect the executive board to detain such a meeting immediately.

        \closing{Expecting an invitation}
        \ps PS: I hope you accept this as an friendly demand note.
    \end{letter}
\end{document}
```